# How can I extract equations from one document for use in another?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I have a LaTeX document that includes many equations.  I would like to create a separate "quick reference" sheet that includes many of these equations.  Instead of copy-and-pasting the equations from the first document to the second document, I would like to be able to reference the equations by name and have them be automatically included (so that if I later change an equation in the first document, that change will be automatically reflected in the second document after I recompile it).  What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use package `extract`:

```
\usepackage[
  active,
  generate=file,
  extract-env={equation,align}
]{extract}
```

Comment: can you selectively extract _some_ equations from the file using that method? Otherwise, one can always define a dummy `\newenvironment{extracteqn}{\equation}{\endequation}` and put `extracteqn` instead of `equation` in the options.

Comment: @Bruno: for example: `figure-nrs={-2,4-},
extract-cmd=chapter,
chapter-nrs={3-5,7}`

Comment: I most definitely _have_ to look into this package.